# In serverless.yml what's the difference between tags and stackTags?

Tags: serverless-framework

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

```
provider:    
  stackTags: # Optional CF stack tags
    key: value
  tags: # Optional service wide function tags
    foo: bar
    baz: qux
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 12):

The CloudFormation stack itself can have tags, which is what `stackTags` is used for.

If you want to tag your Lambda functions you'd use `tags`.

`tags` on a `provider` level are applied to all functions within the stack.

Comment: are stackTags applied to all resources or just the stack itself?

Comment: to all resources. Source: AWS CloudFormation UI, under Tags section, says that stack tags apply to all "supported" resources in the stack.

Comment: `stackTags` are applied to all resources including the CF stack but it's not getting applied to APIGateways. I have not yet been able to find the exact differences b/w these two.